# Impala - Find what tables have a specific column

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala

In Impala, is there a way to check which tables in the database contain a specific column name?

Something like:

```
select tablename, columnname
from dbc.columns
where databasename = 'mydatabasename'
and columnname like '%findthis%'
order by tablename
```

The above query works in a teradata environment, but throws an error in Impala.

Thanks,

Comment: there is no such thing as `dbc.columns` in Impala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Impala shares the metastore with Hive. Unlike traditional RDBMS, Hive metadata is stored in a separate database. In most cases it is in MySQL or Postgres. If you have access to the metastore database, you can run SELECT on table TBLS to get the details about the tables and COLUMNS_V2 to get the details about columns.

If you do not have access to the metastore, the only option is to describe each table to get the column names. If you have a lot of databases and tables, you could write a shell script to get the list of tables using "show tables" and loop around the tables to describe them using "desc tablename".

Comment: I have access to hive but getting errors with tbls & columns_v2

Comment: @acvbasql - You cannot see these tables in Hive/ Impala. You need to find the metastore database and run the queries there. The metastore database details can be found in hive-site.conf. It's is usually an RDBMS.